# Links are not working in new tab or new window

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I can browse all the links, pages or components from base url but not able to open a url like "http://localhost:4200/home/dashboard" in new tab. Its showing blank page.

Note: Even when I am refreshing the page, its showing blank

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorsComponent } from './errors/errors.component';
import { FullComponent } from './layouts/full/full.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';

export const Approutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: FullComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
            },
            {
                path: 'component',
                loadChildren: () => import('./component/component.module').then(m => m.ComponentsModule)
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: WelcomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/',
    }
];
```

Comment: This is likely nothing to do with Angular and related to your server configuration, see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration, but please do some debugging - *why* is the page blank? Errors in the console? Unexpected requests or responses in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) ,
In the documentation, it says -

> A routed application should support "deep links". A deep link is a URL
> that specifies a path to a component inside the app. For example,
> http://www.example.com/heroes/42 is a deep link to the hero detail page
> that displays the hero with id: 42.
>
> There is no issue when the user navigates to that URL from within a
> running client. The Angular router interprets the URL and routes to
> that page and hero.
>
> But clicking a link in an email, entering it in the browser address
> bar, or merely refreshing the browser while on the hero detail page —
> all of these actions are handled by the browser itself, outside the
> running application. The browser makes a direct request to the server
> for that URL, bypassing the router.
>
> A static server routinely returns index.html when it receives a
> request for http://www.example.com/. But it rejects
> http://www.example.com/heroes/42 and returns a 404 - Not Found error
> unless it is configured to return index.html instead.

So my problem was not a problem at all.